# Convert the data frame from long to wide format and dynamically name columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am converting the data frame from long to wide format, however the problem I am facing is generating the right number of translated columns and dynamically renaming the new data frame columns.

So lets say I have a sample data frame as follows:

```
data = {'name':['Tom', 'nick', 'Tom', 'nick','Tom'], 'id':[20, 21, 20, 21,22], 'plan' : [100,101,102,101,100], 'drug' : ['a','b','b','c','a']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
drug id  name   plan
a    20  Tom    100
b    21  nick   101
b    20  Tom    102
c    21  nick   101
a    22  Tom    100
```

So for every given name and id I want to create multiple columns for plan and drugs. For example there are 3 distinct plans and 3 distinct drugs , so ideally I should get 6 new columns which indicate whether a particular plan/drug has been taken or not.

I tried converting from long to wide but I am not getting the desired result.
Convert long to wide:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['name','id'])['plan', 'drug'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values)).unstack().reset_index()
```

Actual output:

```
name    id  0   1    0   1
Tom     20  100 102  a  b
nick    21  101 101  b  c
Tom     22  100 None a  None
```

Expected output:

```
   name    age  100 101 102   a   b  c 
   Tom     20   1   0    1    1   1  0
   Tom     22   1   0    0    1   0  0
   nick    21   0   1    0    0   1  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max`:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['name','id']).astype(str)).max(level=[0,1]).reset_index()
print(df1)
   name  id  plan_100  plan_101  plan_102  drug_a  drug_b  drug_c
0   Tom  20         1         0         1       1       1       0
1  nick  21         0         1         0       0       1       1
2   Tom  22         1         0         0       1       0       0

df2 = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['name','id'])
        .astype(str), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
        .max(level=[0,1])
        .reset_index())
print(df2)
   name  id  100  101  102  a  b  c
0   Tom  20    1    0    1  1  1  0
1  nick  21    0    1    0  0  1  1
2   Tom  22    1    0    0  1  0  0
```

EDIT: Solution with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['name','id'], 
                     columns=['plan'], 
                      aggfunc='size',
                      fill_value=0)

df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['name','id'], 
                     columns=['drug'], 
                      aggfunc='size',
                      fill_value=0)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).clip(upper=1).reset_index()
print(df)
   name  id  100  101  102  a  b  c
0   Tom  20    1    0    1  1  1  0
1   Tom  22    1    0    0  1  0  0
2  nick  21    0    1    0  0  1  1
```

Comment: The solution looks good but there is one problem, for nick plan_101 the value is coming as 2 , although I would just want it to be 1. I tried df1[df1>1] = 0 , but it does not seems to be working on this data frame. Any idea?

Comment: @bakas - ooops, I miss it. Give me a sec.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but pd.get_dummies causes a performance issue and my notebook crashes, given I have close to a million rows, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Thank you so much for your multiple solutions, unfortunately one of my variable has 700 levels and the notebook still crashes. I will accept this answer asthe original question did not take performance into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'name':['Tom', 'nick', 'Tom', 'nick','Tom'],
    'id':[20, 21, 20, 21,22],
    'plan': [100,101,102,101,100],
    'drug': ['a','b','b','c','a']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

plans = df.groupby(['name', 'id', 'plan']).size().unstack()
drugs = df.groupby(['name', 'id', 'drug']).size().unstack()

merged_df = pd.merge(plans, drugs, left_index=True, right_index=True)

merged_df = merged_df.fillna(0)
```

get the `plan` and `drug` counts for each `name` and `id`. (that's what's `size()` and then `unstack()` is for)

and then just merge them on their index (which is set to `name` and `id`).

use `fillna` to replace `NaN` to 0